# 18.04 is slow in VirtualBox—how to make is usable?

Tags: 18.04, virtualbox

I run Ubuntu in VirtualBox.  18.04 is considerably less responsive than 16.04, with exactly the same VM settings (3D acceleration, 3 cores, 4 GB RAM, guest additions installed, host: macOS, VirtualBox 5.2.18).

18.04 is often slow to respond to clicks and even typing. It is borderline unusable. 16.04, on the other hand, works perfectly fine.  The 18.04 is a fresh install.

Is this considerable performance drop an inevitable consequence of switching to Gnome 3?  Are there any simple settings I can try to make it usable?  I do not need animations or fancy visual effects—this in an OS in a VM so it gets only occasional use, and I mostly just need the terminal.

---

**More details:**

- Right after boot, performance is satisfactory
- After opening a Terminal, *and maximizing it*, performance becomes awful. It does not recover even after unmaximizing the Terminal window, or closing it.
- Turning *off* 3D acceleration in VirtualBox makes is more sluggish after startup (e.g. moving window on the screen is choppy), but it never gets *unusably* slow after maximizing a window.

Comment: [There're reports](https://www.virtualbox.org/ticket/17014?cversion=0&cnum_hist=6) that you might be interested in. Also, make sure the VM have got enough RAM.

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1035410/ubuntu-18-04-gnome-hangs-on-virtualbox-with-3d-acceleration-enabled

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I improve the performance of my VirtualBox guest?](/q/190330/175814) and [How do I resolve slow and choppy performance in virtualbox?](/q/287532/175814)

Comment: @DavidFoerster It is not a duplicate. Those QAs are about general nonspecific advice for speeding up Ubuntu in VirtualBox, and sometimes only apply to previous versions.  My question is specifically about a problem with 18.04. I have successfully run Ubuntu 16.04 and many previous versions in VirtualBox.  This is a first-time problem with specific symptoms (such as there being a particular trigger for the slowdown).

Comment: @prusswan Yes, looks like the same problem!

Comment: @DavidFoerster If you want to close as a duplicate, it should be a duplicate of the QA that prusswan linked above. Sadly, that QA also doesn't have any other solution that not using GNOME.

Comment: @Szabolcs: You’re welcome to flag your own question as a duplicate of something else, if you think it appropriate.

Comment: Would the downvoter care to explain what is wrong with the question and how it could be improved??

Answer (score 0):

You can install different desktop environments on Ubuntu. Xfce or Mate are pretty fast. Or even better install fresh Ubuntu Mate or Xubuntu 18.04.

Comment: I am willing to do that if I know that it will help, but before going to this much trouble, I'd like to make sure that the issue is really the desktop environment, and not something else. Note that the base Ubuntu 1604 flavour worked just fine.

Comment: @Szabolcs I wouldn't say that executing a `sudo apt-get install another-de`, following by reboot, and choosing a DE in login screen is much trouble. Sure you spent more time writing the question here than you would for the 3 actions above.

Answer (score 0):

You could install the virtual box guest additions, that optimizes the virtual machine because I have one installed with 512MB RAM and it runs quite well with it.

Comment: I specifically mentioned that the guest additions are already installed.

Answer (score 0):

Check your boot logs:

`sudo journalctl --boot > boot.log`

Sometimes there is stuff that broke (but does not prevent normal booting) which can add to delays. You will be looking for lines that contain "error", "warning" etc

Comment: I specifically mentioned that 18.04 was a fresh install.